# I'm installing cerybot however only getting 0.40.0 when it is up to 1.XX how to rectify

Tags: apt, software-installation, snap, letsencrypt

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I'm pretty new to ubuntu and I see that certbot is installed by default however it is an OLD version.
I've tried apt update etc etc but I'm still left with 0.40.0.
Was wondering how to get to the latest version.

Thanks

Comment: @guiverc Sorry its getting late....brain skip

Comment: `certbot` is not installed by default. You must have installed it some time ago. You'll have to figure out how you installed it - directly using `pip`? `apt-get` using the official Ubuntu repositories? Using the certbot PPA?

Comment: Why exactly do you  want the "latest" version? 20.04's version 0.40.0 works properly.

Comment: Concur with @user535733 I have version 0.4 installed on a server and it has full functionality including autorenewal. If you insist on latest version, the official guidance is to install the snap. https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=apache&os=ubuntu-20

Comment: So it appeared to work with a small error about reading a 1.XX refresh files with 0.4.0 version of certbot.